# Glance Failed to upload image (HTTP 500) and the image status is killed

Tags: image, image-uploading, openstack

This message appear when trying to upload images using glance.

Request returned failure status.
500 Internal Server Error
Failed to upload image 3ea8fe15-43d4-471e-997f-7773117435c3
    (HTTP 500)

```
2014-12-30 17:13:22.096 53553 ERROR glance.store.filesystem [d72c03d7-6b66-47f9-9ce2-d14f4e6b1990 c863caccce4c44519af3cff87a8cf055 99ae8d5d445149a68be9c866d25e6462 - - -] Specify at least 'filesystem_store_datadir' or 'filesystem_store_datadirs' option
2014-12-30 17:13:22.098 53553 WARNING glance.store.base [d72c03d7-6b66-47f9-9ce2-d14f4e6b1990 c863caccce4c44519af3cff87a8cf055 99ae8d5d445149a68be9c866d25e6462 - - -] Failed to configure store correctly: Store filesystem could not be configured correctly. Reason: Specify at least 'filesystem_store_datadir' or 'filesystem_store_datadirs' option Disabling add method.
2014-12-30 17:13:22.131 53553 ERROR glance.api.v1.upload_utils [d72c03d7-6b66-47f9-9ce2-d14f4e6b1990 c863caccce4c44519af3cff87a8cf055 99ae8d5d445149a68be9c866d25e6462 - - -] Failed to upload image b080d409-c278-444f-bad3-67668f66e6f1
2014-12-30 17:13:22.131 53553 TRACE glance.api.v1.upload_utils Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-12-30 17:13:22.131 53553 TRACE glance.api.v1.upload_utils   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glance/api/v1/upload_utils.py", line 105, in upload_data_to_store
```

and when I tried to upload it from the dashboard the image status is killed and then disappeared. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Specify at least 'filesystem_store_datadir' or 'filesystem_store_datadirs' option
```

above line shows that you should set file storing path in glance.conf. try checking it, and after you give directory, restart glance process.

Comment: Thank you. I have already resolved this problem.There something wrong in my glance.conf.